# Usage of warn_unused attribute for classes in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes, gcc-warning

I have the following code:

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class [[warn_unused]] test{
  int val;
  public:
    test() {
      val = 0;
    }
    int getv() { return this->val; }
    ~test() {
      cout << "end\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    test t1;
    int t2 = t1.getv();

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following warnings from the compiler on running `g++ test.cpp`. My g++ version is 9.2.1.

```
test.cpp:4:23: warning: ‘warn_unused’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
    4 | class [[warn_unused]] test{
      |
```

If I change the attribute to `[[gnu::warn_unused]]`, then there are no warnings whether I use the class or not.

Comment: `[[gnu::warn_unused]]` works fine for me: https://godbolt.org/z/sxTZ2Q. If you remove it the warning goes away.

Comment: Looks like `warn_unused` just makes the class work more like fundamental types.  You still need to enable the appropriate warnings.  i.e. it [won't issue a warning without `-Wunused-variable`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/059c4914d49ac3f6).  @lakshay.angrish What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: Although, I couldn't understand why the compiler message in the question description said that the attribute directive was ignored?@MilesBudnek

Comment: @lakshay.angrish Because `warn_used` isn't an attribute, `gnu::warn_unused` is.